# discord.py | List all roles of the member by mentioning the role

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am creating my own stats command but when I try the command it gives me this

```
[<Role id=818899477372600431 name='@everyone'>, <Role id=819591110564642837 name='nw'>]
```

I tried member.roles.mention and member.roles.name but it doesn't work

Code

```
@commands.command()
    async def stats(self, ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
        guild = ctx.guild
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        stats_embed = discord.Embed(title="Member Info") 
        stats_embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Name:", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Account Created At:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name=f"Joined {ctx.guild} At:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Top Role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="All Roles", value=member.roles)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Status:", value=str(member.status), inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Activity/Custom Status:", value=f"{str(member.activity.type).split('.')[-1].title() if member.activity else 'N/A'} {member.activity.name if member.activity else ''}", inline=True)
        stats_embed.add_field(name="Nitro:", value=bool(member.premium_since), inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=stats_embed)
```

So How do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles) is a list of [`role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) objects. If you iterate over every role in the list, you can access their names or mentions individually. To combine all the mentions into a single string, use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) like so:

```py
stats_embed.add_field(name="All Roles", value=" ".join(role.mention for role in member.roles))
```